# Stackoverflow Exception using Scala actors and receiveWithin

Tags: scala, actor

After some time this actor fills out stack. Possible solutions ?

```
object Puller extends Actor {

 def act() = {
  receiveWithin(2000) {
    case Stop => println("stoping puller")
        exit()
    case Noop => println("nothing happens")
        act()
    case TIMEOUT => doPull
        act()
  }
}

  def doPull() = // stuff...
}
```

I'm unhappy to find this code in Programming in Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `act` is not tail-recursive. You can modify it as follows:

```
  @tailrec // in the presence of this annotation, the compiler will complain, if the code is not tail-recursive
  def act() = {
    receiveWithin(2000) {
      case Stop => println("stoping puller"); exit()
      case Noop => println("nothing happens")
      case TIMEOUT => doPull
    }
    act()
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, it stack overflows for very obvious reasons; it's recursive but not tail-recursive. There are two options here:

**Either**: Use a while loop:

```
def act() = 
  while(true) {
    receiveWithin(2000) {
      case Stop    => println("stoping puller"); exit()
      case Noop    => println("nothing happens")
      case TIMEOUT => doPull
    }
  }
```

**Or**: Use `loop` and `react` (which has the added benefit of being scalable by decoupling the actor from hogging a single thread).

```
def act() = 
  loop {
    reactWithin(2000) {
      case Stop    => println("stoping puller"); exit()
      case Noop    => println("nothing happens")
      case TIMEOUT => doPull
    }
  }
```

If this code exists in *Programming in Scala*, it's probably meant more as a proof-of-concept, rather than viable production code. In fact, from memory, it goes on to explain how the recursive `act` calls can be avoided.